# mouse hover with multiple td rowspan

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with multiple `td rowspan`. On mouse hover the entire alphabet row should change to red colour. For example, if we keep the mouse on any alphabet value the entire alphabet section should appear red. Same case for numbers as well.

I tried some jQuery to achieve this, but couldn't get the entire row of alphabet or numbers in same colour.

```js
$("td").hover(function() {
  $el = $(this);
  $el.parent().addClass("hover");

  if ($el.parent().has('td[rowspan]').length == 0) {
    $el
      .parent()
      .prevAll('tr:has(td[rowspan]):first')
      .find('td[rowspan]')
      .addClass("hover");
  }
}, function() {
  $el
    .parent()
    .removeClass("hover")
    .prevAll('tr:has(td[rowspan]):first')
    .find('td[rowspan]')
    .removeClass("hover");
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Alphabet</td>
      <td rowspan="2">a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>f</td>
      <td>g</td>
      <td>h</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Number</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can we solve this?

Comment: Your JSFiddle seems to work fine - on mouseover, the row of numbers/letters goes red.

Comment: ok my bad, its just a formatting issue.

Comment: oops sorry.. here is the link --  http://jsfiddle.net/y3q2bs85/6/

Comment: The easyest way is using nested tables, can you change the html code?

Comment: its not possible because its dynamically grouping and its business call, should use rowspan.

Comment: Why not add a class alphabet to all letter and class number to all number and make : $(".alphabet").addClass("hover"); ?

Comment: As @kmoe said, your fiddle is working exactly as the expected behavior that you explained. What is wrong with it??

Comment: @Samy when I mouse over on Alphabet or any letter, the red colour should be applied to the whole tr...

Comment: It *is* applied to the whole `tr`, you just do not have everything in a row that you would expect in that row.

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore *mouse hover the entire alphabet row should come in red* - guessing this means, "if i hover over alphabet,  i want the three rows highlighted. If i hover over A, i want the two rows highlighted"

Comment: @RajasekharBammidi, *If I hover over 'A'*, do you want 'Alphabet' highlighted also? yes?

Comment: @MrCoder How would that go, if I hover on A, in adition to the two rows after it(b-c and de), the 1st column(with the "Alphabet" text) is selected as well, which means that all other alphabets should be red too.
All in all, he wants the grid to behave as two rows, Alphabets and Numbers, Is that it??

Comment: @MrCoder I want the three rows of alphabet section should be highlighted if I hover over A also.. it means if I hover any letter or Alphabet the three rows should get highlighted.

Comment: @RajasekharBammidi, so [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4vLTP/) is *almost* there?

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore yes you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @RajasekharBammidi, i'm not sure if [this jquery page](http://p.sohei.org/stuff/jquery/tablehover/demo/demo.html) may have it or not? - mainly **Example 6**

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore if I mouse over on either f,g or h then alphabet and f,g,h should come in red not "a".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT: Added a way to find the top of each block.**

**EDIT 2 - Do the hard work up front** Thinking about this again, it is better to just work out at the start which rows are in each block and store that list with each row, e.g. each alphabet row stores a reference to an array containing rows 1-4. So when you hover, you just need to get the array of rows stored in the parent row and apply the class to those.

By checking the maximum rowspan in the top row of the block, you aren't restricted to just checking the first cell. In the updated code, I have moved Alphabet to the middle to demonstrate this and add a couple of other blocks to demonstrate single row blocks work.

```js
function findBlocks(theTable) {
    if ($(theTable).data('hasblockrows') == null) {
        console.log('findBlocks'); // to prove we only run this once

        // we will loop through the rows but skip the ones not in a block
        var rows = $(theTable).find('tr');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length;) {

            var firstRow = rows[i];

            // find max rowspan in this row - this represents the size of the block
            var maxRowspan = 1;
            $(firstRow).find('td').each(function () {
                var attr = parseInt($(this).attr('rowspan') || '1', 10)
                if (attr > maxRowspan) maxRowspan = attr;
            });

            // set to the index in rows we want to go up to
            maxRowspan += i;

            // build up an array and store with each row in this block
            // this is still memory-efficient, as we are just storing a pointer to the same array
            // ... which is also nice becuase we can build the array up in the same loop
            var blockRows = [];
            for (; i < maxRowspan; i++) {
                $(rows[i]).data('blockrows', blockRows);
                blockRows.push(rows[i]);
            }

            // i is now the start of the next block
        }

        // set data against table so we know it has been inited (for if we call it in the hover event)
        $(theTable).data('hasblockrows', 1);
    }
}

$("td").hover(function () {
    $el = $(this);
    //findBlocks($el.closest('table')); // you can call it here or onload as below
    $.each($el.parent().data('blockrows'), function () {
        $(this).find('td').addClass('hover');
    });
}, function () {
    $el = $(this);
    $.each($el.parent().data('blockrows'), function () {
        $(this).find('td').removeClass('hover');
    });
});

findBlocks($('table'));
```

```css
body {
    padding: 50px;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.hover {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Symbols</td>
            <td>+</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td rowspan="4">Alphabet</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">f</td>
            <td>g</td>
            <td>h</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>i</td>
            <td>j</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bitwise</td>
            <td>&amp;</td>
            <td>|</td>
            <td>^</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Number</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. you are close to my requirement but if I have one more rowspan then it is not highlighting entire section because the table has dynamic data. Here is the jsfiddle link :  http://jsfiddle.net/y3q2bs85/14/.. if I mouse over on "f" it is not highlighting entire section in red colour.

Comment: amazing, exactly what I searching for now :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
        $(function () {
        $("td").hover(function () {
            $el = $(this);
            $el.parent().addClass("hover");
            var tdIndex = $('tr').index($el.parent());
            if ($el.parent().has('td[rowspan]').length == 0) {
                $el.parent().prevAll('tr:has(td[rowspan]):first')
                        .find('td[rowspan]').filter(function () {
                            return checkRowSpan(this, tdIndex);
                        }).addClass("hover");
            }
        }, function () {
            $el.parent()
    .removeClass("hover")
    .prevAll('tr:has(td[rowspan]):first')
    .find('td[rowspan]')
    .removeClass("hover");

        });
    });
    function checkRowSpan(element, pIndex) {
        var rowSpan = parseInt($(element).attr('rowspan'));
        var cIndex = $('tr').index($(element).parent());
        return rowSpan >= pIndex + 1 || (cIndex + rowSpan) > pIndex;
    }
```

[Fiddler here](http://jsfiddle.net/v5gjneo1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure is irregular, so it's very hard to find a selector that will select the visual "row", as it spans different rows. One solution is to color the cells by hand, take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2szxsfcs/2/

Basically you tag the rows that are meant to be colored together with the same id, then using jquery you color / uncolor all related TR's:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
        <tr class="fullrow row1" data-id="1">
            <td rowspan="3">Alphabet</td>
            <td rowspan="2">a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  class="fullrow row1" data-id="1">
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>          
        </tr>
        <tr class="fullrow row1" data-id="1">
            <td>f</td>
            <td>g</td>
            <td>h</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="fullrow row2" data-id="2">
            <td rowspan="3">Number</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="fullrow row2" data-id="2">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="fullrow row2" data-id="2">
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        </tr>   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and

```
  $(".fullrow")
    .hover(function() {
        var id=this.getAttribute("data-id");
        // on hover, we get an "id", and all tr's that have class "row<id>" are the ones to color
        $(".row"+id).addClass("hovering"); 
    })
    .on ("blur mouseleave", function() {
      var id=this.getAttribute("data-id");
      $(".row"+id).removeClass("hovering"); 
    });
```

and

```
.hovering { background-color:red; }
```

Comment: that's a clean solution. i.e unless he has to add rows dynamically, in that case he'll have to add logic for adding the class on the rows that must be hovered together.

Comment: yeah... that's the only drawback, but the things you have to add are "dynamic friendly", ie, just the id and the class.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try the <div> way. This solves several problems, but new ones araise.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cforcloud/3wj20bmL/
Note: this uses bootstrap grid system

Its needs little jquery to find the content cells. divs which have no children become .cell

```
$('.row div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).children().length == 0;
})
    .addClass('cell')
    .hover(

function () {
    $(this).parent('.row')
        .addClass('sele');


}, function () {});
```